# Fastest approximate counting algorithm

Tags: algorithm, statistics, machine-learning, probability, graph-algorithm

Whats the fastest way to get an approximate count of number of rows of an input file or std out data stream. FYI, this is a probabilistic algorithm, I can't find many examples online.

The data could just be one or 2 columns coming from an awk script of csv file! Lets say i want an aprox groupby on one of the columns. I would use a database group by but the number of rows are over 6-7 billion. I would like the first approx result In under 3 to 4 seconds. Then run a bayes or something after decisions are made on the prior. Any ideas on a really rough initial group count?

If you can provide the algorithm example in python, or java that would be very helpful.

Comment: Do you know the average line length?  If so, divide the file size by that.  If not, you can look at the first k lines of the file and estimate the average line length from that.

Comment: Yea i will have the apx line size. But this will vary depending on the stream of data. It could just be one column or 2 colums coming from an awk script of csv file! This is more or less like an approximate groupby in sql. Dont care for an exact count of the data. Just an aprox. Any ideas?

Comment: Your first paragraph needs the approximate count of total rows. Your second paragraph needs the approximate count of groupby results. I think the two are different. @Ben Allison's answer is for  your first paragraph and it does not need any training. amit's answer should work significantly better for your second paragraph provided you have good feature extractions. Also in the groupby case, if you do have the total counts, getting the approximate percentage of different values would make more sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Ben Allison's answer is a good way if you want to count the total lines. Since you mentioned the Bayes and the prior, I will add an answer in that direction to calculate the percentage of different groups. (see my comments on your question. I guess if you have an idea of the total and if you want to do a `groupby`, to estimate the percentage of different groups makes more sense).

### The recursive Bayesian update:

I will start by assuming you have only two groups (extensions can be made to make it work for multiple groups, see later explanations for that.), `group1` and `group2`.

For `m` `group1`s out of the first `n` lines(rows) you processed, we denote the event as `M(m,n)`. Obviously you will see `n-m` `group2`s because we assume they are the only two possible groups. So you know the conditional probability of the event `M(m,n)` given the percentage of `group1` (`s`), is given by the binomial distribution with `n` trials. We are trying to estimate `s` in a bayesian way.

The conjugate prior for binomial is beta distribution. So for simplicity, we choose `Beta(1,1)` as the prior (of course, you can pick your own parameters here for `alpha` and `beta`), which is a uniform distribution on (0,1).  Therefor, for this beta distribution, `alpha=1` and `beta=1`.

The recursive update formulas for a binomial + beta prior are as below:

```
if group == 'group1':
    alpha = alpha + 1
else:
    beta = beta + 1
```

The posterior of `s` is actually also a beta distribution:

```
                s^(m+alpha-1) (1-s)^(n-m+beta-1)
p(s| M(m,n)) = ----------------------------------- = Beta (m+alpha, n-m+beta)
                      B(m+alpha, n-m+beta)
```

where `B` is the [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function). To report the estimate result, you can rely on [`Beta` distribution's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) mean and variance, where:

```
mean = alpha/(alpha+beta)
var = alpha*beta/((alpha+beta)**2 * (alpha+beta+1))
```

### The python code: `groupby.py`

So a few lines of python to process your data from `stdin` and estimate the percentage of `group1` would be something like below:

```py
import sys

alpha = 1.
beta = 1.

for line in sys.stdin:
    data = line.strip()
    if data == 'group1':
        alpha += 1.
    elif data == 'group2':
        beta += 1.
    else:
        continue

    mean = alpha/(alpha+beta)
    var = alpha*beta/((alpha+beta)**2 * (alpha+beta+1))
    print 'mean = %.3f, var = %.3f' % (mean, var)
```

### The sample data

I feed a few lines of data to the code:

```
group1
group1
group1
group1
group2
group2
group2
group1
group1
group1
group2
group1
group1
group1
group2
```

### The approximate estimation result

And here is what I get as results:

```
mean = 0.667, var = 0.056
mean = 0.750, var = 0.037
mean = 0.800, var = 0.027
mean = 0.833, var = 0.020
mean = 0.714, var = 0.026
mean = 0.625, var = 0.026
mean = 0.556, var = 0.025
mean = 0.600, var = 0.022
mean = 0.636, var = 0.019
mean = 0.667, var = 0.017
mean = 0.615, var = 0.017
mean = 0.643, var = 0.015
mean = 0.667, var = 0.014
mean = 0.688, var = 0.013
mean = 0.647, var = 0.013
```

The result shows that group1 is estimated to have 64.7% percent up to the 15th row processed (based on our beta(1,1) prior). You might notice that the variance keeps shrinking because we have more and more observation points.

### Multiple groups

Now if you have more than 2 groups, just change the underline distribution from binomial to multinomial, and then the corresponding [conjugate prior](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_prior) would be Dirichlet. Everything else you just make similar changes.

### Further notes

You said you would like the approximate estimate in 3-4 seconds. In this case, you just sample a portion of your data and feed the output to the above script, e.g.,

```
head -n100000 YOURDATA.txt | python groupby.py
```

That's it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Note that this is exactly what I was suggesting, with the addition of the prior. Unless your prior variance is tiny (i.e. alpha + beta is on the same order of magnitude as the sample size), the posterior mean and the ML estimate (what I was suggesting) are going to be identical for most practical purposes. I'm not clear what the advantage of a Bayesian method would be here (which is why I didn't respond to that part of the question :))

Comment: Agree. The OP might be able to take advantage of the Bayesian by using an appropriate prior or/and sampling only a small portion of his data. Otherwise, the posterior mean and the maximum-likelihood estimate is almost identical.

Answer (score 3):

If it's reasonable to assume the data are IID (so there's no bias such as certain types of records occur in certain parts of the stream), then just subsample and scale up the counts by approximate size.

Take say the first million records (this should be processable in a couple of seconds). Its size is *x* units (MB, chars, whatever you care about). The full stream has size *y* where *y* >> *x*. Now, derive counts for whatever you care about from your sample *x*, and simply scale them by the factor *y*/*x* for approximate full-counts. An example: you want to know roughly how many records have column 1 with value *v* in the full stream. The first million records have a file size of 100MB, while the total file size is 10GB. In the first million records, 150,000 of them have value *v* for column 1. So, you assume that in the full 10GB of records, you'll see 150,000 * (10,000,000,000 / 100,000,000) = 15,000,000 with that value. Any statistics you compute on the sample can simply be scaled by the same factor to produce an estimate.

If there is bias in the data such that certain records are more or less likely to be in certain places of the file then you should select your sample records at random (or evenly spaced intervals) from the total set. This is going to ensure an unbiased, representative sample, but probably incur a much greater I/O overhead.